# Powershell Output do not comes in proper format in email body

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, powershell-2.0, sendmail

I am expecting below like output in email from the powershell script.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The above format looks saved in txt file and is looking sme . But when sending it to email BODY it looks like below

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: Please share your code with us.

Comment: Make sure email is HTML and that the output is enclosed in `<pre>` tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `powershell.exe` console displays your formatted output using a monospaced font (ie. fixed-width characters).

Your email client probably doesn't use a monospaced font.

You can specify that the email body is `HTML` and then enclose the formatted output in `<pre>` tags - this will cause most email clients to render it with a monospaced font, preserving all whitespace:

```
foreach ($BODY in $SEND )
{
    $messagebody = $messagebody + $BODY + "`r`n`n"
}

$messagebody = "<pre>$messagebody</pre>"

Send-MailMessage -From "xx@xx.com" -To "yy@yy.com" -BodyAsHtml:$true -Subject "Windows Pstage Disk Status" -Body "Disk are below 20% `n$($messagebody)" -SmtpServer smtp.xxx.com
```